# itemArray data and then skip some value

Tags: c#

```
foreach (string item in textArr)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
        continue;
    if (itemArr[0]='HIS')
        continue;
    if (itemArr[0]='FRAG')
        continue;
    string[] itemArr = item.Split(' ');
    DataRow row=Data.NewRow();
    row["RecordHeader"]=itemArr[0];
    row["ClientName"] = itemArr[1];
    row["Date1"] = itemArr[2];
    row["Date2"] = itemArr[3];
    Data.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Textfile data:

```
ROW1:IMAGE 0 0 0
ROW2:HIS -1 -1 -1 -1    <No need 
ROW3:FRAG 0 0 -1 -1 -1  <No need
ROW4:IMAGE 0 0 0
ROW5:HIS -1 -1 -1 -1    <No need 
ROW6:FRAG 0 0 -1 -1 -1  <No need
ROW7:IMAGE 0 0 0
ROW8:HIS -1 -1 -1 -1    <No need 
ROW9:FRAG 0 0 -1 -1 -1  <No need
```

How to add some changes to skip `ROW2,3,5,6,8&9 DATA`? My idea is if the row data  starts is `HIS` or `FRAG` then skip row. But I do not know make the code work.

Comment: What id the type of `textArr`

Comment: You can use if item.StartsWith("HIS") before splitting the item string.

Comment: @RichaGarg String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some syntax errors in your code with a single equal (=) sign... Try it like that.

```
foreach (string item in textArr) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) continue;
    string[] itemArr = item.Split(' ');
    if (
        itemArr[0] == "HIS" ||
        itemArr[0] == "FRAG"
    ) continue;
    DataRow row = Data.NewRow();
    row["RecordHeader"] = itemArr[0];
    row["ClientName"]   = itemArr[1];
    row["Date1"]        = itemArr[2];
    row["Date2"]        = itemArr[3];
    Data.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: You can't use 'or' in c#. Use || instead

Comment: still have some error: too many characters in character literal.

Comment: || cannot be apply string and char.

Comment: itemArr[0] == 'HIS' should be double quotes "HIS". Single quotes indicate a char.